# Better practice for SQL? One database for shared resources or tables in each Database with those resources

Tags: sql-server

I have shared resources across all of my databases. Users, Companies etc. These are shared between all of my databases and the tables are the same. I want to create on Database for these tables and have all of my databases reference this one instead of having multiple tables that are the same. I come from a C# background and I am not very proficient in SQL. I am writing a new application that uses several of the databases we have.

Question: Should I make one database an authoritative source on these resources? The problem I see is I need Foreign Key relationships between databases and without triggers this is not possible. Not to mention when I write my linq statements I cannot query by these items.

Comment: Which is not a DBMS but a GUI tool to manage a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to achieve this by having one central database as the source of truth, then having copies of the applicable tables moved out to all the databases that needed it via triggers.  You have to make sure all CRUD is done to the source of truth database, otherwise it gets very complicated to manage everything.  You can then create the foreign keys to the copy tables.